# declaring arrays and accepting inputs from the user, recording data

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I need to take input from the user stating name and grades for each person, save the person name with corresponding grades to the array to be able to do the search by name or grades later.
Here's what i got so far

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grades extends JFrame
    {
    String names;
    int results, count;
    int a;
    //declare Buttons
    private JTextField t1, name, grades;
    private JLabel lbl1, namelbl, gradelbl;

    //constructor
    public Grades()
        {
        super("Grades");

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lbl1 = new JLabel("Please enter a number of results");
        c. add(lbl1);

        t1 = new JTextField (2);
        c. add(t1);

        namelbl = new JLabel("Please enter student's name");
        c. add(namelbl);

        name = new JTextField (10);
        c. add(name);

        gradelbl = new JLabel("Please enter student's grade");
        c. add(gradelbl);

        grades = new JTextField (10);
        c. add(grades);


        //create an instance of inner class ButtonHandler
        //to use for button event handling
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

        t1.addActionListener(handler);
        name.addActionListener(handler);
        grades.addActionListener(handler);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        }
    public static void main (String args [])
        {
        Grades app = new Grades();
        app.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter()
            {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {
                System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }

    //inner class for button event handling
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
            Container c = getContentPane();
                if(e.getSource() == t1)
                    {
                    a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                    if (a < 2 || a > 25)
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered wrong value. Please re- enter");
                        t1.requestFocusInWindow();
                        t1.setText("");
                        a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                        }
                    name.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                if(e.getSource() == name)
                    {
                    names = name.getText();
                    grades.requestFocusInWindow();
                    grades.setText("");
                    }
                if(e.getSource() == grades)
                    {
                    results = Integer.parseInt(grades.getText());
                    if(results < 0 || results > 100)
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered wrong value. Please re- enter");
                        grades.requestFocusInWindow();
                        grades.setText("");
                        a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            name.requestFocusInWindow();
                            name.setText("");
                            System.out.println(names + "   " + results);
                        }
                    }

}
}
}
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: My question seems pretty good. I:

Explained the context of my project
Included a detailed list of what I want to accomplish
Showed what I have tried/my work so far
My problem is clear, I need help accomplishing the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

For storing them in an array all you need to do is put them in first.

For example the names array just create a new array:

```
  'String[] namelist = new String[numofnames];'
```

Then to search on it simply use a for loop and check the indexes for the string name you are looking for.  Check if it matches.

Ex.

```
for(int x = 0; x<numofnames; x++)
{
   name.toLowerCase();
   namelist.toLowerCase();
   if(name.equals(namelist[x])
    return x; //return whatever you need
}
```

This should solve this problem.

Comment: What is done is i got name and grades values taken from the user and record them. But i need to put them into an array to be able to perform a search by name or grades later. The question is how do i turn those values into an array element with string and int values?

Comment: To save space you could say name.equalsIgnoresCase() to eliminate the toLowerCase() statements.

Comment: My question is: how can i store values like:

Comment: Peter, 86   Sandra, 89   John, 76    Adam, 90   Clare, 48 in an array

Comment: I would use two arrays for that one for names and one for grades and make sure the indexes line up.  But if you store both you have to store it as a string and use concat method to get the grade part and convert it to an int.

Comment: For storing do it like:  nameslist[0] = "Peter";  If you need to do more at a time depending on how you set it up you can use a forloop and change the "0" to a variable index.

Comment: Well, this is closer to what i need. So, how do i line up indexes for string array and int array if i store them separately?

Comment: Like when you store Peter in index one of the string array, make sure you store 89 in index one of the int array.  This way when you want to access one you can use the same index for both and you only need to search one.